# Hidden line removal in JavaScript or Python?

Tags: javascript, python, 3d, hidden, lines

I have the following task:

- Input:

  A 3D scene comprised of a set of cuboids. Could be broken down to a set of triangles.

  A description of a camera: position, direction, focal length.
- Output: 2D wire frame projection of the scene as a set of lines. Important: Hidden lines removal should have been applied.
- Platform: Web app running on Google App Engine for Python.

Any idea if there is a JavaScript or Python library that does this?

Comment: do you have an idea of how this could be implemented? mainly, how are you going to show the graphics?  

what's this for?  homework?

Comment: How it could be implemented? Look up a hidden lines algorithm and implement it. But I hope that someone else has already done the work.

How to show the graphics? I plan to draw them using Dojo's dojox.gfx (2D).

What's this for? It's a web app that shows a 3D model. And the 3D model doesn't change very often. So the hidden lines generation doesn't need to be quick.

Homework? Fortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Python Nacrisse interface](http://www.python.org/workshops/1996-06/papers/ZaneHTML/) is useful?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I doubt that Nacrisse is able to run on Google App Engine: "Unlike many graphics systems, whose functions are actually linked into one's program, Narcisse runs independently, as a graphics server. The user program communicates with Narcisse via Unix sockets." And, as a plotting tool, it may not be capable of doing what I need.